# How to set the working directory for a Fabric task?

Tags: python, fabric

Assuming I define a trivial task to list files on a remote server:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.use_ssh_config = True

def list_files():
    run('ls')
```

And I execute it with:

```
fab -H server list_files
```

How can I specify the working directory for the command I'm running, other than doing:

```
run('cd /tmp && ls')
```

Which doesn't look very idiomatic to me?

*Disclaimer: I'm looking at Fabric for the first time in my life and I'm totally new to Python.*

Comment: be sure you take a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/tutorial.html), this very question is covered in there.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the [Context Manager `cd`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.cd):

```
from fabric.api import run, env
from fabric.context_managers import cd

env.use_ssh_config = True

def list_files():
    with cd('/tmp'):
        run('ls')
```

Comment: But what if I want **all** of my `run` commands to run in the same directory? Will I have to wrap my entire fabfile in a `with cd()`? Is there not something like `env.working_dir = '/my/dir'`?

Comment: @Dotl if you don't want a huge block wrapped in a context manager, put all the black into a separate function and wrap call to this function into the context manager.

Comment: Note that the `Context` object now is contained within [Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/context.html#invoke.context.Context.cd)

Answer (score 23):

Answer for `fabric 2.4.0` looks like this:

```
from fabric import Connection

conn = Connection(host=HOST_NAME, user=USER_NAME, connect_kwargs={'password': PASSWORD})

with conn.cd('/tmp/'):
    conn.run('ls -la')
```

This is not covered by the `fabric` documentation but by the [`invoke` documentation](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/context.html#invoke.context.Context.cd).

Comment: The fabric documentation suggests doing `with Connection('host') as c:`, so would you nest the with statements inside of each other?
`with Connection('host') as c:
   with c.cd('/tmp/'):`